Semantic Versioning - pre release
I have latest release version ex. v1.6.0 (master)
then I create new prerelease and it automatically creates pre release + tag
v1.6.0-develop.1 (develop branch)
the problem is that in github releases page and tags page the order is as fallows:
10 minute ago - v1.6.0 (latest)
1 minute ago - v1.6.0-develop.1 (prerelease)
how can I change the order so v1.6.0-develop.1 will be above v1.6.0 (latest) ?

You could use a validation for your pull request to dont allow merge to the release branch if the prerelease pipeline is running

You can't (or if you find a way, shouldn't, including if you can manage to coerce tooling to list them in different orders). This violates both the spirit and the law of semantic versioning. Effectively, you're doing it backwards.
Your best bet is to either start with pre-releases in the first place and then up the version to a release version or to start with a given version and bump the appropriate value in the triad (major, minor, patch) according to the semver rules. If you want this future version to be pre-release, then you also append the "-description" part.

Right: 1.6.0 to 1.6.1 or 1.7.0 or 2.0.0
Right: 1.6.0 to 1.6.1-develop.1 or 1.7.0-develop.1 or 2.0.0-develop.1
Wrong: 1.6.0 to 1.6.0-develop.1
Right: 1.6.0-develop.1 to 1.6.0


@kit is correct, to expand on his answer ...
I see the issue is caused by having a 1.6.0-develop.1 after 1.6.0 was released. The next version after the 1.6.0 release must be one of:

1.6.1
1.7.0
2.0.0

NuGet enforces that you can only ever publish a 1.6.0 package once. So in this case "release" is when you publish to NuGet :-). You can build as many 1.6.0 as you like but you can only release one of those once.
The important question is what does your team define as a release? (such a big question)
